# what are the best/standard practices for handling state changes and custom content ( login / activity / news ) in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, android, ios, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile to put together a native app. version of a webapp.

I've run into a handful of issues related to caching as I migrate the site.  I'm wondering if others can offer suggestions.

To customize content for signed-in users, my web-app changes content delivered to the browser based on their `login-state` and uses a `no-cache` header.  This works fine on normal sites.

On the jQuery Mobile site that I've been coding up, the way that caching works has created an issue.

For example, the splash page template contains this logic:

```
% if logged_in:
    <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
% else:
    <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Register for Free</a></li>
% endif
```

Because jQuery Mobile caches the page, when I go back to the homepage after signing out, I see the "logged_in" contents - unless I do a page refresh.

I can imagine this will also cause issues when I start to deal with time-based news and content in the app.

Right now I've figured out a few tricks to get around caching and related issues:

1. use `data-ajax="false"` on form submits
2. append a random element to the query string

Going through a handful of existing sites built on jQuery Mobile, I see that people seem to be forcing page refreshes via JavaScript often.  I considered using JavaScript to do content personalization too ( logged-in`vs`logged-out ), but realized that won't work for the 'news' content concerns.

The docs don't seem to address these sort of questions and scenarios so I was hoping that the StackOverflow community could make some suggestions.

Comment: "I'm using jQuery Mobile to put together a native app. version of a webapp." - LOL - JQM will never be a "native app" ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I got around this was to remove the page div from the DOM before it is loaded each time.

If the page is cached then it will be removed from the DOM and reloaded, if it isn't cached then nothing will be done so there is no overhead.

So attach an onclick to your links that calls .remove() on the requested page div before the page is requested.

However, version 1.0 should do this automatically:

> **DOM size management**
>
> For animated page transitions to work, the pages you're transitioning from and to both need to be in the DOM. However, keeping old pages in the DOM quickly fills the browser's memory, and can cause some mobile browsers to slow down or even crash.
>
> jQuery Mobile therefore has a simple mechanism to keep the DOM tidy. Whenever it loads a page via Ajax, jQuery Mobile flags the page to be removed from the DOM when you navigate away from it later (technically, on the pagehide event). If you revisit a removed page, the browser may be able to retrieve the page's HTML file from its cache. If not, it refetches the file from the server. (In the case of nested list views, jQuery Mobile removes all the pages that make up the nested list once you navigate to a page that's not part of the list.)
>
> Pages inside a multi-page template aren't affected by this feature at all - jQuery Mobile only removes pages loaded via Ajax.

Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-cache.html

Comment: that's an interesting approach...  i like it.

i'm wondering if i could do this on top of your concept:
1. have an onLogin that removes certain pages
2. have another call that removes pages from a certain timestamped cache.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think you don't need a server-side component to render such a template - just a waste of resources (unless you got some more specific code running like that, then it depends).

Me - I went with utilitizing JQM at the client side - such a template as you posted is EASY to switch at the client side, much faster - better user experience - and save network resources!

For example, I use the JQuery event model to fire my own custom events (i.e. loggedIn / loggedOut) and a UI event handler that switches the visiblity of those DIVs based on the event. Happens immediately, no network delay!

Just my $.02...

Comment: i thought of that approach earlier.  that's how i typically add a login-status to web pages, but thought it might make sense to save myself an ajax call.  although.. i guess i could use javascript cookies to cache login status.

how do you handle 'refreshing' a timely page?

Comment: "save myself an ajax call" - not sure you are saving anything by hitting the server (whether by ajax or directly). Note that (most) mobiles support sessionStorage which would be a (safer) alternative to save state in between page loads (event thought with JQM you could have it all in one page so no reloads!)